# How to destructure objects from Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

The following code works when implemented with only React, but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: _ref is not iterable

specifically on destructuring `[id, name]` when I start using Redux:

```
class GridView extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.itemList.map(([id, name]) =>
                    <Item
                        key={id}
                        name={name}
                        id={id}
                    />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect((state) => ({itemList: state.itemList}), actions)(GridView);
```

It works if I write it like this instead:

```
class GridView extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.itemList.map(el =>
                    <Item
                        key={el.id}
                        name={el.name}
                        id={el.id}
                    />)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect((state) => ({itemList: state.itemList}), actions)(GridView);
```

I don't understand what it means by _ref.  Is there a way to properly destructure data retrieved from the Redux store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with Redux. You need to use **curly braces** (`{}`) when destructuring an object, not **square brackets** (`[]`), which would be to destructure an array.

```
{this.props.itemList.map(({ id, name }) => (
  <Item
    key={id}
    name={name}
    id={id}
  />
))}
```